# Schedule Grunt task

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, scheduled-tasks, grunt-contrib-watch

I search a way to schedule Grunt task with a Grunt plugin. I found nothing.

Is that possible to look at the time with "watch" and execute a task if it's time ?

Comment: Watch works with changes in the file system. The task is executed when a file is changed. For your requirement a cron job should do the job.